How can I subtract 3 hours from a user-provided date and time in a Bash script?
im working on a Bash script where I need to subtract 3 hours from user-provided start and end date/time inputs. The user inputs the date and time in the 24-hour format as DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS.
#user will enter 24hours format
Select_Start_date="01/10/2024 12:55:23"
Select_End_date="01/10/2024 16:54:23"

# Convert to the correct format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) before subtracting hours
S_date_adj=$(date -d "$(echo $Select_Start_date | awk -F'/' '{print $3"-"$2"-"$1" "$4}')" -d "3 hours ago" +"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
E_date_adj=$(date -d "$(echo $Select_End_date | awk -F'/' '{print $3"-"$2"-"$1" "$4}')" -d "3 hours ago" +"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

echo "Actual start date: $Select_Start_date"
echo "Actual End date : $Select_End_date"
echo "Reducted 3 hours start date:$S_date_adj"
echo "Reducted 3 houes End  date :$E_date_adj"
    
    # Pipeline Query
    SELECT ord.order_num FROM database.s_order ord,
         database.S_ORDER_DTL dtl
    WHERE ord.created >= TO_DATE('$S_date_adj', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
      AND ord.last_upd <= TO_DATE('$E_date_adj', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')

I need help ensuring that the date subtraction is correctly 24 hrs formatted and applied in the SQL query.
Result i got:
Actual start date: 01/10/2024 12:55:23
Actual End date : 01/10/2024 16:54:23
Reducted 3 hours start date:03/10/2024 08:21:49 ( Suppose 12 -3 =9:55:23)
Reducted 3 houes End  date :03/10/2024 08:21:49 ( suppose 16-3 =14:54:23)

$ Select_Start_date="01/10/2024 12:55:23"
$ date -d "$Select_Start_date"
Wed Jan 10 12:55:23 EST 2024
$ date -d "- 3 hours $Select_Start_date"
Wed Jan 10 09:55:23 EST 2024
$ date -d "$Select_Start_date - 3 hours"
Wed Jan 10 11:55:23 EST 2024

Putting the delta time first works OK
When you put -3 after the datetime, the date parser interprets that as the timezone offset.
All the gory details at Date input formats

Thank you for your response. The date format should not change; it should remain the same as the user's entry so that it can be passed directly into the query. Below is the solution I received. Thank you!
Select_Start_date="01/10/2024 12:55:23"
Adjusted_Start_date=$(date -d "-3 hours $Select_Start_date" +"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
